# Insertar datos en SQL Server sin estar esta instalado en mi equipo

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, .net, tcp

Quiero saber si existe alguna forma de insertar datos en una base de datos que esta en **SQL Server** sin tener alguna de las versiones de esta instalada o tener **Visual Studio** instalado e mi equipo.

Estos son los datos que poseo:

- **server** = tcp:"Enlace para conectarse a la BD", 1433
- **usuario** = nombreusuario
- **pass** = contraseña

Comment: Este es libre y sirve para muchos tipos de bases de datos. Yo lo uso con Postgres y funciona bien. DBeaver Free Universal SQL Client dbeaver.jkiss.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eso sí es posible, ambas computadoras/servidores donde el sistema se ejecutará y donde estará el SQL Server instalado deben pertenecer a la misma red.

En caso no anden en la misma red, una VPN es una posible solución :D

Ahora, si a lo que te refieres es a un software para administrar y/o ejecutar consultas, te recomiendo el mismo SQL Server Management Studio https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms y si en caso buscas una buena alternativa a ello, utiliza este: http://www.squirrelsql.org/

Comment: me aparece este error **database engine tuning advisor does not support Microsoft Azure SQL Dtabase**

Comment: agrega todos los detalles de la aplicación que estás desarrollando y actualizaré la respuesta :D Por cierto, con qué software intentaste conectarte?

Comment: Con el de microsoft, pues la aplicacion la hizo un amigo que esta en la parte del Back-End, de igual forma voy a intentar con el otro

Comment: Maestro ya funciono, creo que estaba abriendo la herramienta que no era o al menos eso creo que pasaba, gracias por todo.

Comment: de nada mi hermano, gracias por el halago :D estamos para servir, sigue adelante! éxitos y bendiciones :D

Comment: De paso asumo, que para realizar la comprobación del servidor si esta bien o no es solo con una petición, mas nada.

Comment: Asegúrate que la IP de donde te conectas esté en la lista de excepciones del firewall de Azure para que te conectes sin problemas :D

Comment: Si ya funciono, creo que estaba abriendo alguna de las versiones que se instala que no es la adecuada, pero todo listo ya puedo guardar datos, lastima que sea todo código puro, pero toca hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set cnn = New Adodb.Connection
            cnn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
            cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
                                   "server=195.248.589.11; " & _
                                   "database=Basedatos; " & _
                                   "uid=Usuario;pwd=password"
                                    cnn.Open
```

Comment: Lo que busco es poder conectarme e insertar datos, pero usando alguna herramienta con algun entorno tipo MySQL WorkBench

Answer (score 0):

Tambien, tienes esta opción

[Toad Sql Server](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/550)

Comment: si buena opcion, pero ya uso una propia de microsft

Answer (score -1):

Podrias conectarte usando Navicat es un manejador de base de datos.

Comment: Pero navicat es de pago o me equivoco, de igual forma, voy a echarle un ojo.